# How are values referenced in a "double assignment"

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I was curious, so I tried this out:

```
var test = example = 5;
```

Now, this is a somewhat common way of defining things...

(for instance in node, `module.exports = exports = ...`)

The above be equivalent to:

```
example = 5;
var test = example;
```

Now, if variables don't actually hold a value, but are rather references to values in the memory, when I change `example`, if `test` is referencing `example` which is referencing a value, shouldn't `test` also have that same value as `example`?  Lets try it:

```
var test = example = 5;
example = 7;

console.log(test, example);
```

... Now, the output isn't really what I expected, due to what I put above..  You get this:

```
5 7
```

But how is `test` still `5` if `test` is referencing `example`, and `example` is now `7`?  Shouldn't they both be `7`?

---

**`EDIT`** Tried using Objects instead...  But I get the same behavior:

```
var test = example = {"hello":"world", "foo":"bar"};
example = {"test":"example"};
console.log(test, example);
```

This outputs:

```
Object {hello: "world", foo: "bar"} 
Object {test: "example"}
```

So, they're still not the same like I expected.

Comment: Numbers are immutable and everything is passed by value.

Comment: If you used an object instead of 5, then you would achieve the result you are expecting, because js objects are mutable

Comment: @elclanrs it's actually not about immutability (at all), but about "calling by sharing" (it would be exactly the same behaviour even if you used a mutable `{}` instead of `5`)

Comment: @Ananth no, they would not (and again - it has nothing to do with immutability)

Comment: Actually `var test = example = 5;` is equivalent to `example = 5; var test = 5;`. Assignment returns right value by spec

Comment: @Zhegan, alright thanks.  But even so I still get the same effect.

Comment: @Jamen why should it be different? References != pointers. With pointers you would get such a behaviour.

Comment: > var test = example = {}
> test.blabla = 'b'
> example

Output: Object {blabla: "b"}

Comment: Seems like it should reference the same value in the memory, maybe I just don't completely understand.

Comment: @Jamen they do reference to the same value in memory. Then you create another object and put a reference to it to just one variable. The other variable still holds a reference to the old one.

Comment: Ohh, I see.  That's pretty much the answer to this post then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = {}; // There is one object in memory
var b = a;  // now both `b` and `a` refer to that object

a = {};     // now we create another object and put a reference to it to an `a`
            // we haven't changed `b` so it refers to the former object
```

And to summarize: in JS you cannot change the value of another variable. Value of variables `a` and `b` in the example above is a *reference*, not the object itself. And the only way to change the value of the variable - is to re-assign another value to it. So you cannot change the value of a variable indirectly in JS, at all (?).

Comment: So, just curious, if you remove all references to that first object, would the object be destroyed? Or (for instance if we were in a web browser) would we have to wait until the page reloads?

Comment: @Jamen if an object in the heap is not reachable (there are no any references to it) then a JS engine is free to garbage collect it. But it's not obliged to do so, since the standard does not qualify how engines should perform garbage collection. And to be 100% precise - it does not require an engine to have a garbage collector at all.

Comment: If two variables reference the same object, and you add a property to one of the variables, couldn't it be argued that you've indirectly "changed" the other variable?

Comment: @RickHitchcock you don't change a variable. You change the object in the heap. The values of the variables are still the same reference. It's like - you have a postal address like `42, Foo bar avenue`. I have the same postal address. And a guy with name "A A" lives there. Then he moves somewhere else and now a lady "B B" lives there. We have the same reference (address), it has not changed. But the contents (the tenant) has changed. `zerkms.friend_address = rick.friend_address = { tenant: 'A A' }; zerkms.friend_address.tenant = 'B B';`

Comment: Right, I understand how that works.  But if a variable's property has changed, some might argue that the variable's "value" has changed.  Example at http://jsfiddle.net/744tawy1/1/

Comment: @RickHitchcock "some might argue" --- and it's fine :-) This is a tricky terminology question so no wondering some people have hard time getting into it. The main part is that the object is not a value or a variable, but a reference is. "if a variable's property has changed" --- and it's critically important to not say "a variable's property", since a variable does not have one, it's an object property has changed, which a variable refers to.

Answer (score 0):

When speaking about java script, variables can accept multiply values. JavaScript is a very 'forgiving' language let's call it like this.

So, if you said for example:

```
 var test = example = 5;
```

test would still be 5, because test is now given the value of 5. test is but a reference in this case to example.

the actual value of example, is 7.

```
example = 7;
```

So yes, it's a bit odd, But javascript behaves a bit differently then other programming languages.

Comment: "But javascript behaves a bit differently then other programming languages." --- like what "other" languages for example? I see it behaves the same way like majority of languages I ever worked with.

Comment: `test` is not a reference to `example`.  Instead, it's the result of the expression `(example=5)`, which is simply `5`.